# Create a simple chart in PowerPoint not working

Tags: charts, powerpoint

I have following problem, i can not create a simple chart with PowerPoint:

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim gChartData As ChartData
Dim gWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim gWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

' Create the chart and set a reference to the chart data.
Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set gChartData = myChart.ChartData

' Set the Workbook and Worksheet references.
Set gWorkBook = gChartData.Workbook
Set gWorkSheet = gWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
```

In Line Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) etc. following error:
Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

in line Set gChartData = myChart.   if i press CtrL + space, i don't see the paramather ChartData, just ChartArea.

Something is not working appropiately. The references that i have are:
Visual Basic For Applications
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsofot Office 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Feeds
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

The code was copied from the website from microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973127%28v=office.14%29.aspx

How can it be possible that i use some code from microsoft and it doesn't work...? very frustrating.

Regards

Comment: and i got also in the line of .ChartData:

Compile error: method or data member not found.

I am missing any references?

Comment: Your example code works here in PPT 2010 (ie, 14.0).  Have you tried repairing your Office installation (ie, via Control Panel)?

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. No i didnt,  i am sorry, what do you mean with repair? do u need that i have to install office again? would be a problem, because people from IT need to take time for that and that costs us money. Any ideas how can i fix the problem? how can it be possible that i just copy paste a code from microsoft, and it doesn't work?

Comment: >> how can it be possible that i just copy paste a code from microsoft, and it doesn't work?   Some of their example code is garbage, for one thing.  And if there's a problem with your office installation, even good code may fail.  So go to Control Panel | Programs & Features, select Microsoft Office and choose Change then go through the steps to repair it.